# C# android multiple screen sizes support

Tags: c#, android, screen

I have build an android app that only works on a 4 inch display. When I test it on a bigger or smaller screen, some of the buttons and textboxes is either too big or too small. How do I make it compatible with multiple screen sizes?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: check the documentation on developer.android.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supporting multiple screen layouts and resolution can be hard but there is good practices to make your activity more responsive when supporting multiple screens.

You should not use fixed dimension in any elements. For example don't ever use for example button size to be 20px. Instead using pixels (**px**) it is recommended to use use Density-independent pixel (**dp**).

Density-independent pixel (**dp**) is recommended in Android to specify dimensions in a independent manner of screen size.

Second tip is to use **Relative Layout** as much as you can, with RelativeLayout, which uses relative positioning to lay out its child views you can make more responsive layout for your app activity.

And the hardest way is to make multiple activities for multiple resolutions by creating different layouts for different screen.

If you work with images in your app make sure that you have **vectors** and not use bitmap images for you components like button or something like that, best practice is to follow material design concept of simplicity of UI.

See more [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html) about support for vectors. If you have bitmap images then make sure that you have all kinds of sizes for your image, use drawable folders for separation of images:

> drawable-mdpi
>
> drawable-hdpi
>
> drawable-xhdpi
>
> drawable-xxhdpi

And I strongly recommend you to take a look at the official documentation about [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) read all document and always make sure that test you screen size on multiple emulators or devices with different densities.

Answer (score 0):

Read this documentation...this may help you...

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: But do I have to design a new layout for each screen size?

Comment: had you the fixed the size of all the views? please post some part of your design.